# Objective-c iOS prototype cell reverting after redraw

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a dynamic cell, populating prototype cell from a db.

When I click on a cell it changes color and database is updated.

However when the cell scrolls outside the screen, it is back to original color.
If I open and close the program, the cell will be the correct color, since database was updated.

Reloading entire table does not help.
I checked and database is being updated right after the click on cell.

Answer (score 1):

when cells go out of view and get reused (with identifier...) a cell that is coming into view is taking over the cell that went out of the view, and thereby setting all its changes to that of a new cell.

you will have to keep track of the select cells yourself, and when that cell comes into view you can do a separate initialization returning it to its old state. Just keep track of its indexPath.row and you should be fine.

Comment: could you explain a little more please?

Comment: hmm, put it this way, when a cell goes out of view, its effectively recycled. `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called on the new cell that is coming into view and however you are setting up your cells in the method will override the cell going out. The table view does this so that it doesnt have to delete the cell going out and recreate a cell coming in, which is quite wasteful. Instead it just takes the cell that was going out, and changes its variables basically to look like a new cell.

Comment: this is quite an important optimization otherwise if you have a table with 10000 cells, you app will run out of memory, so it instead creates only the amount that can fit into view, and when the cell comes into view, it reuses an old cell that went out of view. so that 10000 cells can map to just a few.

Comment: so you can just keep a variable say `selectedRow` then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, just have an if statement like `if(indexPath.row == selectedRow){//setup selected cell}else{//setup default cell}`